# Нет ссылки на объект

Tags: unity3d

Всем привет. Не могу использовать статический массив. Пишет сылка на объект не установлена в экземпляр объекта.
     первый скрипт с переменной

```
 public static int[] Card; 

void Metod(){ Card[0] = 0; }
```

второй скрипт

```
  if(HeroOwl.Card[0] == 0){

    }
```

Comment: приходится куски кода писать :
public static bool SelectCardP1_0 = false;
    public static bool SelectCardP1_1 = false;
    public static bool SelectCardP1_2 = false;
    public static bool SelectCardP1_3 = false;

    public static bool SelectCardP2_0 = false;
    public static bool SelectCardP2_1 = false;
    public static bool SelectCardP2_2 = false;
    public static bool SelectCardP2_3 = false;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Верно, массив объявлен, но не проинициализирован , добавьте

```
 public static int[] Card = new int[10];
```

или проинициализируйте его в статическом конструкторе

Comment: Благодарю сеньор. Было бы безупречно если бы вы посоветовали книгу по сишарпу(не справочник, ибо без практики я мало что улавливаю). Благодарю заранее.

Comment: Не стоит благодарности, начал бы с чего-то такого.  https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5-ne4MEmmf-Q2gwbW9weDNmdUE если с английским не плохо. Попутно Юнити освежите.